# Pandas DataFrame.assign() doesn't work properly for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I am trying to reassign multiple columns in DataFrame with modifications.
The below is a simplified example.

```
import pandas as pd 
d = {'col1':[1,2], 'col2':[3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

I use assign() method to add 1 to both 'col1' and 'col2'.
However, the result is to add 1 only to 'col2' and copy the result to 'col1'.

```
df2 = df.assign(**{c: lambda x: x[c] + 1 for c in ['col1','col2']})
print(df2)
   col1  col2
0     4     4
1     5     5
```

Can someone explain why this is happening, and also suggest a correct way to apply assign() to multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `lambda` here can not be used within the for loop `dict`

```
df.assign(**{c: df[c] + 1 for c in ['col1','col2']})
```

Comment: Can you explain why lambda cannot be used?

Comment: @JKLim you called lambda twice within the for loop, and you want to create the dict first , however, the dict values have the function lambda